# Show component if 'true', else show other component (in React)

Tags: html, reactjs, hide, state, show

Im trying to show one or the other component in React. I can show a component on click, but I cant show the other.

React code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Motion, spring } from 'react-motion'

import Header from '../../components/services/Header'
import ServiceSelector from '../../components/services/ServiceSelector'
import PriceCalculator from '../../components/services/PriceCalculator'
import VVSRequest from '../../components/services/VvsRequest'
import VVSFeatures from '../../components/services/VVSFeatures'
import GalleryPreview from '../../components/services/GalleryPreview'
import Footer from '../../components/services/Footer'

require('styles/_servicesPage/services.css')
require('styles/_servicesPage/serviceSelector.css')
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');

export default class Services extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.state = {
      showPriceCalculator: false
    }
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const userChoice = e.target.className
    this.setState({ userChoice })
  }

  toggleDiv(toggle) {
    console.log('te',toggle);
    this.setState({showPriceCalculator: toggle})
  }

  render() {
    var styleVar = {
      backgroundImage: 'url(assets/images/services/service_bg.jpg)'
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <ServiceSelector toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)}/>

        {this.state.showPriceCalculator ?
          <PriceCalculator toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)}/> : <VVSFeatures />}

          {/*<VVSFeatures />
          <VVSRequest />*/}

        <GalleryPreview />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

On load it shows the

```
<VVSFeatures />
```

as it should

but after the state is set to

```
showPriceCalculator: true
```

and then is set again to false, nothing happens (the  should appear again)

It rerenders with the right state value, but nothing happens. 
What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure the state is correct? Also, I don't know where you are using that `handleClick` but `this.setState({ userChoice })` might be overwriting your state. Maybe put a console.log of the state inside the render so you can see it at every point to double check? Where is the part of the code that is setting it back to false?

Comment: How do you know `It rerenders with the right state`? can you do `console.log('showPriceCalculator: ',this.state.showPriceCalculator)` after `render() {` and let us know if you see the right value?

Comment: Yes I logged out state inside the render method and I printed true when I from ServiceSelector set it to true, and it printed false when I set it to false from the PriceCalculator component.

Comment: Are you sure it's the boolean true/false and not a string then? You should show the code where you set it to false. As you can see with that answer from Piotr below, your logic is fine, so you must be setting something incorrectly.

Comment: .... what's it?

Comment: "Are you sure it's the boolean true/false and not a string then?"
I set the value to 'true' as the parameter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I set the value to 'true' as the parameter, i.e a string not a boolean

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared a working demo for you here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/yaVaLK

Would this solution work for your intended use?

```
class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showPriceCalculator: false
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const userChoice = e.target.className
    this.setState({
      userChoice
    })
  }

  toggleDiv() {
    this.setState({
      showPriceCalculator: !this.state.showPriceCalculator
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Header</div>
        <ServiceSelector toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)} />

        {this.state.showPriceCalculator ? <div toggleDiv={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)}>PriceCalt</div> : <div>VVSFeatures</div>}

      </div>
    );
  }
}


class ServiceSelector extends React.Component {
  toggleDiv() {
    this.props.toggleDiv()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p onClick={this.toggleDiv.bind(this)}>Click here - ServiceSelector</p>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The toggle value can come from ServiceSelector component or the PriceCalculator which I think will lead to inconsistent results.  Consider the case when ServiceSelector calls this.props.toggleDiv(true) and then PriceCalculator components also calls this.props.toggleDiv(true). You are not actually toggling. The state for controlling is spread in different places. Infact, you dont need send any toggle parameter from any of these components.

You can just

```
  toggleDiv() {
    this.setState({showPriceCalculator: !this.state.showPriceCalculator})
  }
```

Comment: I agree with that, the naming is a bit off. The reason for that is if I press one div it should only be able to set to true, and vice versa. But this does not help the problem that the parent component doesn't re-render the component!
(ps, it did not downvote)